# Can't Find the unresolved external symbol (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unresolved-external

Doing assignment for class.  Getting this error message:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: Mulvihill_Program_7, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>Mulvihill_Program_7.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl calcGross(void)" (?calcGross@@YANXZ) referenced in function _main
    1>c:\users\pat\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Mulvihill_Program_7\Debug\Mulvihill_Program_7.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int getHoursWorked();
double getPayRate();
double calcGross();

int hoursWorked = 0;
double payRate = 0.0;
double grossPay = 0.0;
double OVERTIME = 1.5;
double overTimePayRate = 0.0;
double pay = 0.0;



int main()
{

    getHoursWorked();
    getPayRate();
    pay = calcGross();

    cout<<pay;
}

int getHoursWorked()
{
    cout<<"Enter the amount of hours worked ";
    cin>>hoursWorked;

    return(hoursWorked);
}

double getPayRate()
{
    cout<<"How much do you make an hour? ";
    cin>>payRate;

    return(payRate);

}

double calcGross(int hoursWorked, double payRate)
{
    if (payRate < 40)
    {
        grossPay = hoursWorked * payRate;
    }
    else
    {
        overTimePayRate = OVERTIME * payRate;
        grossPay = hoursWorked * overTimePayRate;
    }
    return(grossPay);
}
```

I know there's probably a lot more wrong with this code than just the error in terms of conventions, and stuff, but I'm new at this, and I'm just trying to understand the error message for now.

Comment: Does `calcGross` take two parameters or none? Your code can't seem to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker cannot find this function definition,

```
double calcGross();
```

because you define the function as such,

```
double calcGross(int hoursWorked, double payRate)
```

Should you remove the parameters so that the function declaration & definition are matched.
Change your function declaration like this,

```
int getHoursWorked();
double getPayRate();
double calcGross(int hoursWorked, double payRate);
```

Then pass the value of `hoursWorked` & `payRate` when calling it in `main()`

Comment: Don't I need to put the variables that I want to pass into the function  in calcGross(paramaterList)?

Comment: @user3085359: so you have to change your function declaration.

Comment: The function prototypes have to match the function definitions. In this case, you probably want to change the prototype (top) to match the actual function definitions (bottom).

Comment: I charged the function declaration to what you said for calcGross, and called calcGross(hoursWorked,payRate); in the main function, but I got the same error.  By removing the arguments from the functions completely, the program compiles and works, but it doesn't do the overtime calculation properly.

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: Mulvihill_Program_7, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Mulvihill_Program_7.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl calcGross(int,double)" (?calcGross@@YANHN@Z) referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\pat\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Mulvihill_Program_7\Debug\Mulvihill_Program_7.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @user3085359: I don't know why this. But first, plz check the function's prototype with the definition again, and the function's calling. Second, if still error, move the function's definition before **main()**.

Answer (score 0):

Your calcGross() definition has a different type signature from the one that is called in main(). main() is calling a calcGross() without any arguments which is a totally different function from the calcGross() with two arguments -- int and double.

Just add

```
double calcGross()
{
    // replace with your logic
    return 0.0;
}
```

to the code and you'll not get any linker errors. Or supply the required arguments to the calcGross(int, double) definition.

Refer to [type signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) in Wiki for additional details.